# When are Transformers better than LSTMs in time-series tasks such as classification?

Tags: classification, transformer, long-short-term-memory, time-series

I’m working on a time-series classification problem and trying to decide whether to use a Transformer or an LSTM.

From what I’ve learned, Transformers are better suited for capturing long-range dependencies in time-series data vs LSTM. The transformers are an excellent option for processing word data for Natural Language tasks, and frameworks are currently built to represent time-series data, such as TabTransformer and TimeSeriesTransformer models.

But I’m unsure if that’s always the case.

Are there specific use cases where Transformers are better than LSTMs for time-series classification?

What are some key differences between the two architectures in representing time-series data?

Answer (score 1):

Both the architecture have some use cases based on their architecture.

**Transformer**

- Transformers are good when there are long-range dependencies, in those cases they outperform the LSTMs.
- Main key feature is High dimensional data in those cases self-attention is very useful.
- In terms of processing Transformer allows parallel processing during training which leads to faster training.
- In terms of feature interaction this model is very efficient in mapping complex feature relations.

**LSTM**

- It is designed to deal with sequential data and catch dependencies effectively, only for shorter sequences.
- When you have limited data for training LSTM generalizes better because of fewer parameters than the Transformer.
- It is more suitable for online learning and real-time processing because it processes data sequentially.
- It is less demanding in terms of computation.

**Main differences:**

- **Mechanism**: The Transformer uses attention to weigh the importance of different parts of the input, which helps to learn global
  dependencies, while LSTM processes data sequentially and uses a gate
  mechanism for informal flow control, which struggles in long
  sequences.
- **Memory**:LSTM has an inbuilt memory cell state that carries information, which helps in time-series-based patterns while
  Transformer doesn't have recursive memory but has positional encoding
  to understand sequence order.
- **Complexity**:Transformer has a high number of params because of self-attention head and FFN (feed-forward network) while LSTM has
  fewer params which is beneficial in case of limited data.